# Getting text from a website and putting it into one line?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

How can i get all the text from a website (URL:http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hydro698) and put it into a single line string, rather than more than one line, currently it will have around 20 lines give or take, but i want it to be in a single line.

Code for retreiving text:

```
public static void getTextFromURL() {
    URL url;
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hydro698");
        is = url.openStream();    // throws an IOException
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            // nothing to see here
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: You dont have to give me all the code, just a point in the right direction. :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, change the `System.out.println` to `System.out.print`. Done. :-D

To return a `String` instead, simply create a `StringBuilder` outside the loop, then `append` each line of the input to it.

---

Sample code to demonstrate the latter (I just realised what the OP wants, which is spaces instead of newlines):

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if (result.length() != 0)
        result.append(' ');
    result.append(line);
}
return result.toString();
```

Hiren Patel's style of reading each character works too:

```
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
while ((c = br.read()) != -1)
    result.append(c == '\n' ? ' ' : (char) c);
return result.toString();
```

Comment: Wow i feel stupid now :) But does than mean my string will be in that line or just where `print` has been used?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. Do you just want to print the line to the screen, or do you want to return a string? If the latter, as my answer mentioned, just create a `StringBuilder` and `append` each line you read from the page.

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the output instead of line to by character,
i.e. from `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)`  use `while (int c != -1)` read all characters and put them in a stringbuilder.
Then print the string at the end.

Edit:
use below code, it works:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        URL url;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hydro698");
            is = url.openStream(); // throws an IOException            
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int ch = is.read();
            while (ch != -1) 
            {
                if((char)ch != '\n')                
                    baos.write(ch);
                ch = is.read();
            }
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            String st = new String(data);
            System.out.println(st);
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                // nothing to see here
            }
        }
    }
```

Output is: 
`501844,110,34581332115,30,14114403982,1,18325274,31,15814460203,14,2405287276,11,1366419761,1,67679445,1,0505401,1,70522524,1,75454208,1,0505244,1,20505816,1,40469998,1,0337042,2,155393308,5,437403072,1,0488016,1,0524106,1,0428961,1,0389021,1,0382198,1,0383592,1,0362267,1,0-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1-1,-1`

Hope when u run, u will understand that output is in a single line. `String st = new String(data)` is holding it.

Comment: Nah, that'd include the newlines too. The OP wants to remove the newlines.

Comment: You know, when you read the output by a single character, you can check whether reading character is '\n' then do not add to string builder, otherwise add to string builder. This will ensure you will have only 1 string at the end and no '\n'. OR you can replace '\n' with ' ' (space). You will have more power when you read by individual character rather than reading by line. Hope this will solve your query.

Comment: What can i say, I am at work and also check the forum and replying, :)

Comment: This code works to get the characters, but i have a problem appending them? CODE:     
    `int c = 0;
    while((c = br.read()) != -1) {
     char character = (char) c;
            sb.append(character);
     System.out.println(sb);
     
    }`

Comment: @ Will, try using the code which i am about to add by editing my original post. I know the problem.

Comment: i dont think this i what i need, If you check out the source code of: `http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=Hydro698` That is how i have it currently, but, i want it to be in a single long line instead. (how it is when you dont look at the source)

Comment: @HirenPatel Why on earth would you use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` when a `StringBuilder` works just fine? See my edited answer.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young-Yes, u can use StringBuilder.But remember it is not efficient coding practise. Everytime you do sb.append("something"), it creats a new string in buffer and then append it to original string. When u read data from website, you need efficiency. How can you explain that everytime a char is read, you create a new string, I hope u know strings are immutable objects.StringBuilder spec says a new string is created everytime append is called. So hence you use `ByteArrayOutputStream`, they are fast and efficient. But @Will Baker has different prob now, which i will get back 2u soon

Comment: @WillBaker I ran my code again. It WORKS. But if u just copy+paste my code then it will still print '\n'. You have to make sure you read my comment regarding checking the character if newLine then skip otherwise add. I have again edited my code to add that line. I did ran on my machine and it works. If this solves your problem then plz vote up.